# How do you check if something is stored in a PHP array?

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I have a feeling this question must have been asked before on this site, but for the life of me I cannot find the exact equivalent.

I want to check for the presence of a specific value in a multidimensional `PHP array`. For example:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [publishDate] => 2013-02-22 01:51:39 
        [visible] => 1 
    ) 
    [1] => 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 4 
        [publishDate] => 2013-02-22 02:49:58 
        [visible] => 1 
    ) 
    [2] => 
    Array ( 
        [id] => 7 
        [publishDate] => 2013-02-22 02:50:21 
        [visible] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

Does "1" exist under the `id` key? (It exists in the `publishDate` key and in the `visible` key, but I don't wish to check those fields.)

So basically "1", "4" and "7" would return TRUE. While everything else would return FALSE.

This must be possible, but `array_search` and `array_key_exists` don't seem to be giving me what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: something like `$arr[0][visible] == 1` ?

Comment: Basically you can always write your own function, if there is no built-in functions available for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly (imo), your best bet would probably be to just write your own function.

```
function visibleID($array, $id)
{
    foreach ($array as $entry)
    {
        if ($entry['id'] === $id)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm sure if you could write a more generic function if you wanted (ie pass the 'visiblity' key as func arg) but that's up to you.

Comment: Why are you checking the 'visible' key? Just to make an example?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt For some reason I read that you wanted to check visibility's equal to 1 in your post, fail. Glad to hear it worked though!

Answer (score 0):

You can write more generic function to check key value pair By extending above function :

```
function visibleID($array, $id)
{
    foreach ($array as $entry)
    {
        if( is_array($entry) ) {
        array_map('visibleID',$entry); //-------------call back function 
        } else {
            if ($entry['id'] === $id)
             return true;
       }
    }

     return false;
}
```

//-------------this function will work  on any dimension array even both array(homogeneous and hetrogeneous)